# Why Pound symbol (£) is converted to question mark (?) in Postman?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have set some error code and message in a JSON file in my project which looks like (not original code for safety):

```
{
"ERROR":"Limit is £100."
}
```

When I set this message to be thrown as exception when testing from Postman, instead of showing `Limit is £100.`, it shows like `Limit is ?100.`

So, I'm worried why `£` gets converted to `?`. Then, I tried to replace this **?** with **£** by using below code:

```
String message = fetchErrorMessage("ERROR", ***some parameters***);
if (message != null) {
message = message.contains("�")
        ? message.replaceAll("�", "£")
        : message;
}
```

**Note: I checked with � instead of **?** because when I was debugging the code and hover over the `message` to check whether it contains the `£` symbol or not, I found that it was having a weird looking square block (check screenshot below). So, I copy-paste it and got to know it's a question mark symbol inside a black diamond.**
[image]

Now, with above piece of code change, the message is coming properly in Postman but soon I realized that when I deployed the code in UAT environment, it still shows `?`.

So, any workaround how to fix it?

Comment: Wrong encoding used.  Need UTF-8.  Is Postman assuming ASCII?

Comment: Nope, content-type = application/json and I also tried adding charset=utf-8 in content-type but still shows ? in UAT env.

Comment: That's fine for the HTTP request.  What about the Postman display?  Your problem occurs in the last mile when rendering on the UI.

Comment: @duffymo not yet integrated with UI. But when I debugged it, I can see ? symbol there also, so if that's the case, how UI can convert it into pound by itself? Only after integration we will get to know.

Comment: That's the part that needs to be figured out.  Sounds like the data is there.  Need to make sure the renderer is interpreting it correctly.

Comment: Try swagger UI and see what the data looks like?

Comment: @Enfieldli I can't use swagger UI cuz testing of api required tons of headers to be passed which I don't know how to pass via swagger UI. So far no help yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific character that shows up wrong when UTF-8 is set from the client(SoapUI) in the header content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8.
For more details [Check this link](https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/72616/western-european-characters-do-not-displ.html)

Comment: It's not the client, I have set the pound symbol in my message which is in json file and upon reading it when exception is being thrown, it shows ? symbol instead of pound symbol. I tried many workaround to successfully make it work but it still ended up looking like the same in postman console, even though the logs shows the pound symbol.